# php script only allowing one function with a parameter to be called

Tags: php, function

I have written a php class with 2 functions in but when i call the functions inside of a different script it only allows 1 of the 2 functions to run.

this is the script with the functions.

```
<?php

 define('RDFAPI_INCLUDE_DIR', 'rdfapi-php/api/');
 require_once('SimpleRdfParser.php');




 class retrieve{

 public $p;
 public $uri;
 public $rdf;

 function retrieve(){ 
   $this->p = new SimpleRdfParser();
   $this->uri = 'rdfs/crime.owl';
   $this->rdf = @file($this->uri);
}

function getName(){

 return "heyyy";
}

public function getL1Comment($type){
  /*
    this function gets the comments that are to do with the main type of crime i.e.       Sexual Offences
*/ 

if (is_array($this->rdf)) {
  $this->rdf = join('',  $this->rdf);
  if (is_array($data = $this->p->string2triples($this->rdf, $this->uri))) {

     $val = $data["http://localhost/".$type][2][1][0];

     return $val;
     exit;     
  }
 }

}

public function getChildComment($crime){

/*
  this function gets the comments from the child node of the main type of crime i.e. Rape of a Female aged 16 and over, 
  this is a child node of Sexual Offences
*/

if (is_array($this->rdf)) {
$this->rdf = join('',  $this->rdf);
if (is_array($data = $this->p->string2triples($this->rdf, $this->uri))) {

    $val = $data["http://localhost/".$crime][2][1][0];

    return $val;
    exit;     
   }
  }
 }




}
```

and this is the script calling it:

```
<?php

 require('retrieve.php');

 $type = $_POST["type"];
 $crime = $_POST["crime"];

 $q = new retrieve();

echo $q->getL1Comment($type)."<br />";
//print($q->getL1Comment($type)."<br />");
print($q->getName());
//print($q->getName());
echo $q->getChildComment($crime);


?>
```

does anybody have any idea as to why this is happening?

thank you in advance

Comment: your `getL1Comment` has `exit` in it, which causes the execution to stop; remove it and it will go through the rest of the code

Comment: Isn't the `exit` statement never reached? The function's execution should terminate on the `return` statement, never reaching `exit`.

Comment: i removed the `exit` and it is still not calling it

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is why:

They both do this `$this->rdf = join('',  $this->rdf);`

and they both are conditional on this:

```
if (is_array($this->rdf))
```

So the first is causing the array to no longer be an array. Thus, the second method's conditional will fail.

Try something like this:

```
public function getL1Comment($type){
  /*
    this function gets the comments that are to do with the main type of crime i.e.       Sexual Offences
*/ 

  if (is_array($data = $this->p->string2triples(join('',  $this->rdf), $this->uri))) {
     $val = $data["http://localhost/".$type][2][1][0];

     return $val;
  }
}
```

that way you're not redefining $this->rdf in the methods, since as I see it there is no reason to do this.

Comment: thank you, i tried what you suggested and it gave me and error further into the API that i am using so i tried putting it in the constructor and it worked fine.

Answer (score 1):

exit;  <== this is killing it

Try removing exit from inside your function and put it in after your calls are done.

Answer (score -1):

you have exit in your function so it is escaped before going to the next function